# How hide/show all paragraphs with a certain text-style?

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I'm trying to find a way with VBA to hide/show a certain text-style.

What's the best way to make a sub like this in VBA?

I'm going to add the code to a "Hide/show" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ThisDocument.Styles("StyleToToggle").Font.Hidden = Not ThisDocument.Styles("StyleToToggle").Font.Hidden
```

Comment: Thanks! This was much more simple then the if-then-else I was trying to set up. Cheers!